# Python regex prefers longer fuzzy match to shorter exact match

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex in Python to search for multiple patterns in a string. A simplified example would be as follows:

```
import regex
s = "vrhvydhvkzejjvksdlstringvhehvehvurejlcslvdk"  #string to look into
p = ['(?P<string>string)', '(?P<longtext>longtext)']  #patterns to search for
r = regex.compile('(?b)(' + " | ".join(p) + '){s<=3}')  #regex, allowing for 3 mismatches, bestmatch to be reported
r.search(s)   #searching for patterns p in string s
<regex.Match object; span=(18, 25), match='stringv', fuzzy_counts=(1, 0, 0)>   #search results
```

My expected result would be:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(18, 24), match='string', fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 0)>
```

Why do regex reports a fuzzy match `stringv` with 1 mismatch instead of reporting the exact match `string`? And how do I need to modify my code to get to my expected results?

I am with Python-3.7.3 and regex 2.5.115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'(?e)(' + " | ".join(p) + '){s<=3}'` results in a `(?e)((?P<string>string) | (?P<longtext>longtext)){s<=3}` regex, see the spaces around `|`. Since `v` is substituted for a space when matching the `(?P<string>string)`  regex part, you get `stringv` as a match.

You need

```py
r = regex.compile('(?b)(' + "|".join(p) + '){s<=3}')  #regex, allowing for 3 mismatches, bestmatch to be reported
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##NZDNboMwDMfvPIVFD0k0xIVr271C79MOFDwSCEnkeCndx7OzAJpkyZ/55W@HJ2vvmnU1c/DEQDjgUkS4QJlIp2ev0/SF45im2NvIZNyQNOqU7ZNwtF20qZ9KgNPRBPZgvZ/AOPZFyJw3IV9v56N7PZwSFexV693AuPD1P1DiPaNCy4zk4gaL2FKn4cNTQUvG5XeopIAXKH/KevTGyaByJtR3PF@aXwEF5bF9j7rzczAWJS0qY/daBa21/rFJzUxoYDZxbrnTGCu4Y@Q92X6@Y6ZsR8G@CFk2S6D6kCOjArWufw):

```py
import regex
s = "vrhvydhvkzejjvksdlstringvhehvehvurejlcslvdk"  #string to look into
p = ['(?P<string>string)', '(?P<longtext>longtext)']  #patterns to search for
rx = '(?e)(' + "|".join(p) + '){s<=3}' 
r = regex.compile(rx)  #regex, allowing for 3 mismatches, bestmatch to be reported
print( r.search(s) )
# => <regex.Match object; span=(18, 24), match='string'>
```